# WooCommerce - custom product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm planning a WooCommerce plugin which should override the default shop page "product grid" with my own (a masonry grid with custom styling, pagination and filters).
I see that many developers include template pages in their plugins (archive-product.php) to customize the shop loop output; is this the only way to do it?
I'm asking because I would let the user to customize his grid in WP admin screen (you know, changing columns count, products per page, load-more button/infinite scroll, etc).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, it's not the only way. You can also register your own custom template in your plugin, which can be called pretty much anything.